# C++: Using typedef to make a code flexible

Tags: c++, class

Consider I'm using an GNU (or GPM) biginteger library that is of type mpz_t. However, I may use a different library in the future. I want my code to be easily  changed when I use a different library, so I should not need to change all types of variables using mpz_t.

Thus, my question is whether it is a good OO design if I first define:

```
typedef mpz_t bigint;
```

then use bigint all over my code? If not, what other options could be used?

Comment: typedef is often used for exactly this. Go for it!... If you believe all the interfaces will be the same.

Comment: @Patrick what do you mean by " If you believe all the interfaces will be the same", please.

Comment: This has nothing to do with OOP, but it is generally a good practice

Comment: If you change libraries, you'll have to change a lot more than just the type of your variables. Every API call to that library will also have to change. Another option is to make an abstract big integer class and have your code use that, and create a new subclass for any new libraries.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths For the second option (i.e. using abstract class), do I need to redefine all methods that uses the original library?

Comment: @Adrian: You wouldn't need to redefine them when you changed library, but you would need to write a new subclass to call the functions in your new library. That's the whole point of making an abstract class, here, you can add new functionality without needing to change anything in the code that uses it. But obviously you still have to write the functionality to use the new library, which you'd have to do anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here one can see the trade off between readability and the easiness for the developer. Some typedefs that aim to do what you describe are just awful, because they are not limited to a logical amount of types, thus it makes the code hard to read and maintain for others ... and you (when time passes).

You could give the `typedef` a chance and see what happens. Consider using a separate file (but this is *optional*) to do all the manipulation you need when using another library (if this is applicable of course). Then you will have to check/modify only one file of your project (super-useful when the project is large).